# How to display notification alert popup after clicked on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, notifications

I am using notification alert popup plugin (http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Growl-Notification-Plugin-For-jQuery-jsnotify/)

I have to display notification alert after clicked on submit button if there are some error in the text field. My below code, It is displaying an alert when I clicked inside the text field and continuously displaying when clicked.And how can I use for an alert for the second text field? Would you help me in this?

```js
  $('#myDiv').click(function(){
  var options1 = {
  'title': 'Error',
  'style': 'error',
  'message': 'Invalid name',
  'icon': 'warning',
  };
  var n1 = new notify(options1);
  n1.show();
  });
```

```css
  body { background-color:#f7f7f7; font-family:'Roboto';}
  .container { margin:70px auto;}
```

```html
  <script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Growl-Notification-Plugin-For-jQuery-jsnotify/dist/js/notify.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Growl-Notification-Plugin-For-jQuery-jsnotify/dist/css/notify.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
  
  <form action="" method="post" id="myDiv">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="n1">
  <input type="text" name="mobile" id="n2">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="click me">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using that plugin in wrong manner. You are calling `click` event on `div` which was registering `click` event on `div` container. So, even if you click insider that container (not on inputs and button) it is showing pop up.

I've put everything in `$(document).ready()` and calling pop up when you have non-empty filed on `form` submission. You can replicas same for second input field.

Working example - http://jsbin.com/watacirasu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Kalpesh Singh. Working for me but I have to display alert only one time. It is displaying every time when I am clicking on submit button.would you help me in this?

Comment: And How can I use for an alert for a second text field?

Comment: I'm working on second field alert and one time alert issue. Native plugin doesn't have this functionality. So, I'm applying my work around.

Comment: Thanks for replying Again Mr.Kalpesh. It is working great but I got one more issue in this. Like without entered any data in the field and submitted then It is displaying both alert popup which is great but after if I field one field then clicked on submit then it is displaying last alert popup and new alert popup. Means total numbers for alert popup are 3.

Comment: I've updated JSBin. It'll hide once you try to enter again. I'm finding this plugin very limited. I would suggest you to go for other similar types of plugins. You are doing many custom things here!

Comment: Yes, Now it is working. Do you know about other plugins because I checked on Google. There are lots of plugins but I have to use plugin as an alert like validation.

Comment: Thanks for replying again. I will try that also.

Answer (score 2):

### You may check form at submit event like shown below

```js
$('#myDiv').submit(function(){

var firstinput = $("#n1").val();
var secinput = $("#n2").val();
 
  if(firstinput == "")
  {
  var options = {
  'title': 'Error',
  'style': 'error',
  'message': 'Invalid Name',
  'icon': 'warning',
  };
   var n1 = new notify(options);
   n1.show();
  }
  else if (secinput == "")
  {
   var options = {
  'title': 'Error',
  'style': 'error',
  'message': 'Invalid Mobile',
  'icon': 'warning',
  };
  var n2 = new notify(options);
  n2.show();
  }
  else { 
    console.log('form submitted');
    }
  });
```

```css
body { background-color:#f7f7f7; font-family:'Roboto';}
  .container { margin:70px auto;}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Growl-Notification-Plugin-For-jQuery-jsnotify/dist/js/notify.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Growl-Notification-Plugin-For-jQuery-jsnotify/dist/css/notify.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
  
  <form action="" method="post" id="myDiv">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="n1">
  <input type="text" name="mobile" id="n2">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="click me">
  </form>
```

Comment: Why are you assigning all variables on each for submit?

Comment: Then declare the variables outside, not in the `submit` function.

Comment: Not blaming the script, brother. Just for best practice.

Comment: thanks@KalpeshSingh but if i define variable before submit then script can't read these values and gives undefined ....

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Aman Kumar. I checked your snippet when L clicked on click here nothing is happing

Comment: really but working fine on my system .. please check once again ... thanks

Comment: Yes, Mr.Aman Kumar, I am using firefox and when I clicked on click me nothing is happing.

Comment: It doesn't run for me either